# How do I test a Web-Service with Single-Sign-On authentification?

Tags: soapui, sap

I am trying to test a Web-Service that is created in an SAP System with SoapUI.

Normally I would provide a user name and password in order to authenticate the call.

The problem that I am having is that I can only log in to SAP using Single-Sign-On. Is there a way to configure it somehow in SoapUI? Unfortunately I have not found any tutorial on this topic.

Comment: My advice would be to talk to the SAP people to set up normal login or token based authentication (you get a token on login and use it in subsequent calls), in order to facilitate testing. Assuming you are in a test environment, of course. Sometimes the solution is people and not technology.

Comment: Unfortunately there is absolutely no way to ask for that. It is the policy of the project. The other thing is, that it would run exactly the same way in the production so why test it in a completely different way?

Answer (score 2):

Have never used SoapUI before, but in similar situations one way is to manually log in via SSO, then grab the cookie (or similar) it leaves from browser DevTools and copy that into the requests sent by API testing tool. (It's still not automated but can at least avoid needing to only test by making requests from the DevTools console).

This SO post seems to discuss this approach a little in the context of SoapUI - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28022721/sending-cookie-as-request-header-in-soap-ui-request-for-rest-web-service